# Using setTimeout() in React and Testing it

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

I realized that I have been using `setTimeout()` in my project -maybe- more than I should, I did a quick research and scroll through some open source react projects on Github and decided I should ask about it.

I use `setTimeout` mostly for changing the classname or adding styles to animate the DOM objects also using CSS transition, one point I thought it will be hard to write unit testing with this many setTimeout.

Since I came from using AngularJS, there is a `$timeout` service which has the same functionality with setTimeout, but in testing you can flush the timeout like `$timeout.flush()` and the timeout ends instantly.

**My questions;**

- Is there an alternative testable way that I can use instead setTimeout (logicly or programaticly)?
- Is there any builtin testable function in React does the same thing with `setTimeout`?
- Is there any react addons I can use for "flushable" timeout?

Keep in mind I'm fairly new at reactjs and haven't write any unit test on it yet.

Comment: (1) Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379082/react-how-to-test-out-react-compoennt-with-settimeout) will help you with that? (2) No. (3) Not that I know of.

Comment: @Chris I saw that question, but it is asking if he can test the component using setTimeout, I'm using setTimeout in my actual code and want to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you are using. There's a sinonjs fake timers (http://sinonjs.org/) and Jest also has this functionality (with an example): https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/timer-mocks.html

Cheers,
  Mariusz

Comment: This actually works for me, thank you. I wonder if you can elaborate on what "it depends"?

Comment: I meant "it depends" in context of which library you're currently using:) Both approaches are correct.