# How to test a React component that render its content after a Timeout?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The component is a Pop-Up that render its content after a setTimeout (let's say after 3 seconds)

When I try to test it the content is not render so it can't find any element to do the asserts

How can I test a component like this?

Comment: How about you add a setTimeout to your test as well? As it's expected behaviour, I don't see why not

Comment: @rdalpra tests are meant to run quickly adding 30 seconds timeout for example would be very annoying.

Comment: I don't see a way around this though. If the expected behaviour is to have a timeout, you have to test for a timeout, I'd say. Let's wait for the experts to show up :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using setTimeout() in React and Testing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634832/using-settimeout-in-react-and-testing-it)

Answer (score 1):

One of popular solutions is to use [jest fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks).